# amsthm: Punctuation only when there is a title

Tags: theorems, amsthm

So I have the following style for theorems, lemmas, etc.

```
\newtheoremstyle{Fancyplain}
{\topsep}   
{\topsep}   
{\itshape}  
{0pt}       
{\bfseries} 
{:}         
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} 
{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}. \thmnote{\normalfont\bfseries#3}}
```

Essentially it looks like this:

**Theorem 11. Theorem Title:**

However, I don't want the colon to appear when the theorem has no title. Because it looks like this:

**Theorem 12.:**

Is there any way to do this? My current solution is to have no punctuation, and manually add the colon when I have a title.

Comment: I had overlooked a little bug that caused improper spacing when the title is missing: please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply move the colon inside the argument of `\thmnote`?  **Note:** I have edited the code in order to correct a bug, that I had overlooked, concerning proper spacing when the title is missing.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{Fancyplain}
{\topsep}   
{\topsep}   
{\itshape}  
{0pt}       
{\bfseries} 
{}         
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} 
{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}.\thmnote{\ #3:}}

\theoremstyle{Fancyplain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Thorem}



\begin{document}

Text text text.

\begin{thm}
    Without a title.
\end{thm}

Text text text.

\begin{thm}[A title]
    With a title.
\end{thm}

Text text text.

\end{document}
```

The picture showing the output has been changed accordingly:

[image: Output of the amended code]